# Magento2: Show custom currency symbol in specific store view

Tags: magento-2.1

How to show custom currency symbol in specific store view based on local location ar_SA or ar_EG ?

I tried XML files inside vendor\magento\zendframework1\library\Zend\Locale\Data\ but not working.

Magento 2.1.6